# Check continuity of a function f(x)

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity

Let $f$ be a function

$f(x)$ = $x/(x^2+25)$ if $x$ is from $Q$

$f(x)$ = $(|x-2|)/(x+25)$ if $x$ is from $R/Q$

Possible points at which function is continuous are 1 and 5.
Let's consider point 1.
Since $f(1)$ = $1/26$
and left and right limit of both rational and irrational sequences is $1/26$ when x aprroaches 1, can I conclude without epsilon delta proof that function is continious at 1?

Comment: Here's a lemma which you might want to show:
Let $f(x)  = \begin{cases} g(x) & x \in Q  \\ h(x) & x \not\in Q \end{cases}$. Then $f(x)$ is continuous at $x_0$ iff $g(x_0) = h(x_0)$.

Comment: Kaind thank you